# Passing a string in a function (C)

Tags: c, string

I have this small program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define SIZE 30

void inverti (char s);

int main ()
{
        char str[SIZE+1];

        gets(str);

        printf ("Your imput: ");
        puts(str);

        invert(*str);

        printf ("It works!");

        return 0;
}

void invert (char s)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE + 1; i++)
    {
        if (isupper(str[i]))
            str[i] = tolower(str[i]);

        else if (islower(str[i]))
            str[i] = toupper(str[i]);
    }

    puts(str);
}
```

were is the error? Why i can't pass `str` to my function?

```
In function ‘main’:|
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘inverti’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]|
note: expected ‘char’ but argument is of type ‘char *’|
In function ‘invert’:|
error: ‘str’ undeclared (first use in this function)|
note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in|
||=== Build finished: 3 errors, 1 warnings ===|
```

Comment: Question has been answered, but why do you call this function `invert`? That's not what it does at all.

Comment: The function should "invert" a lower char with an upper char... maybe my bad english is the matter :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your code has at least 3 problems.

First, and most relevant to your specific question, you've declared the argument to your function as a single character: `char`. To pass a C string, declare the argument as `char *` - a pointer to a character is the type also used for a C string:

```
void invert(char *str)
```

And you won't need to dereference when passing the argument:

```
invert(str);
```

Also note that you've mis-typed the name of the function in your function prototype: you've called it `inverti` there. The name in the prototype **must** match the name in the function definition later in the code.

You'll also need to change the argument type in your corrected and renamed function prototype:

```
void invert(char *str);
```

Your code has one additional problem: you're iterating over the string using `SIZE`. `SIZE` is the maximum size of your array, but not necessarily the size of your string: what if the user types in only 5 characters? You should review and use the function [`strlen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) to get the actual length, and in your loop, only iterate over the actual length of your string.

Comment: Do I need t declare the "str" function again in the "void invert(char *str)" function? Why it says to me "error: ‘str’ undeclared (first use in this function)"?

Comment: no, it's declared in the argument list. If you declare it in the arg list as: _void invert(char *str)_ then you can use it within the function. Did you change the name to _str_ in your function argument list? In your code you had it as just _s_.

Comment: modifying the code in the way you proposed, Code::Blocks warns me with error: ‘str’ undeclared (first use in this function)..

Comment: go through your code line by line carefully. You've probably mis-typed something. Be sure that in the function, you're using _str_ everywhere, including the function argument list, declared as `void invert(char *s)`.